# convert scala.collection.Iterator to java list

Tags: scala, arraylist, iterator

Is there any direct API to convert scala.collection.Iterator to java list.

I tried following things:

```
val xs = Iterator[POJO]
println("xs size : " + xs.size)
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
val p = Lists.newArrayList(xs)
**output** :
xs size : 1
p : [empty iterator]
```

case 2:

```
val input:Iterator[POJO] = xs.asJava
val m = ImmutableList.copyOf(input)
println("m value : " + m.toString())
**output**:
xs size : 1
m value : []
```

case 3:

```
val n = xs.toList.asJava;
println("n value : " + n.toString())
**output**
n value : []
```

Comment: please include an example iterator with a handful of elements, so that we have some test data to replicate the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterator can be consumed exactly once and I can see that you try to reuse the same iterator for the *case 3* even though conversion itself is correct.

Below you can find simple function that converts scala iterator to java list using approach in *case 3:*

```
  def iteratorToJavaList[T](iterator: Iterator[T]): java.util.List[T] = {
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    iterator.toList.asJava
  }
```

and it can be used like this:

```
val scalaIterator = List(1, 2, 3).iterator
println(iteratorToJavaList(scalaIterator))
```

which results:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct I was trying all the 3 options in block only.. thanks:)

Comment: No problems, please either mark answer as correct or close the question :)